# eBay XML Api - list an item with Overnight free shipping

Tags: python, xml, ebay-api, ebay-sdk

I'm trying to list an item with global free shipping via the eBay API, I'm having issues figuring out the exact parameters to the `ShippingDetails`.
I have attached images of what I'm trying to achieve in a listing and the XML that I am using at the moment, note that I am getting `Input data is invalid. Input data for tag <Item.ShippingDetails> is invalid or missing. Please check API documentation`' At the moment.[image]

XML Data:

```
def list_new_item():
    response = api.execute('AddFixedPriceItem', {
        'Item': {
            'Title': 'Random book',
            'Description': 'This is a random book item',
            'PrimaryCategory': {'CategoryID': '38583'},
            'StartPrice': '1.0',
            'CategoryMappingAllowed': 'true',
            'ConditionID': '1000',
            'Country': 'US',
            'Currency': 'USD',
            'DispatchTimeMax': '3',
            'ListingDuration': 'Days_30',
            'ListingType': 'FixedPriceItem',
            'PictureDetails': {
                'PictureURL': ['https://example.com']
            },
            "Location": "Calexico, California",
            'Quantity': '0',
            "ShippingDetails": {
                "ShippingServiceOptions": [
                    {
                        "ShippingServicePriority": 1,
                        "ShippingService": "Overnight",
                        "ShippingServiceCost": "0.00",
                        "FreeShipping": True,
                        "ShippingTimeMax": 1
                    }
                ]
                        },
            'ReturnPolicy': {
                'ReturnsAcceptedOption': 'ReturnsNotAccepted'
            }
        }
    })

    return response.dict()
```

Comment: Could you please share a minimal working example and a xml dummy file, please?